# How can I get a custom python type and avoid importing a python module every time a C function is called

Tags: python-import, python-module, python-c-api

I am writing some functions for a C extension module for python and need to import a module I wrote directly in python for access to a custom python type. I use `PyImport_ImportModule()` in the body of my C function, then `PyObject_GetAttrString()` on the module to get the custom python type. This executes every time the C function is called and seems like it's not very efficient and may not be best practice. I'm looking for a way to have access to the python custom type as a `PyObject*` or `PyTypeObject*` in my source code for efficiency and I may need the type in more than one C function also.

Right now the function looks something like

```c
static PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) 
{
    PyObject* myPythonModule = PyImport_ImportModule("my.python.module");
    if (!myPythonModule)
        return NULL;

    PyObject* myPythonType = PyObject_GetAttrString(myPythonModule, "MyPythonType");
    if (!myPythonType) {
        Py_DECREF(myPythonModule);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* more code to create and return a MyPythonType instance */
}
```

To avoid retrieving `myPythonType` every function call I tried adding a global variable to hold the object at the top of my C file

```c
static PyObject* myPythonType;
```

and initialized it in the module init function similar to the old function body

```c
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_mymodule(void)
{
    /* more initializing here */

    PyObject* myPythonModule = PyImport_ImportModule("my.python.module");
    if (!myPythonModule) {
        /* clean-up code here */
        return NULL;
    }

    // set the static global variable here
    myPythonType = PyObject_GetAttrString(myPythonModule, "MyPythonType");
    Py_DECREF(myPythonModule);
    if (!myPythonType) {
        /* clean-up code here */
        return NULL;

    /* finish initializing module */
}
```

which worked, however I am unsure how to `Py_DECREF` the global variable whenever the module is finished being used. Is there a way to do that or even a better way to solve this whole problem I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just calling import each time probably isn't as bad as you think - Python does internally keep a list of imported modules, so the second time you call it on the same module the cost is much lower. So this *might* be an acceptable solution.

Second, the global variable approach should work, but you're right that it doesn't get cleaned up. This is rarely a problem because modules are rarely unloaded (and most extension modules don't really support it), but it isn't great. It also won't work with isolated sub-interpreters (which isn't much of a concern now, but may become more more popular in future).

The most robust way to do it needs [multi-phase initialization](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#multi-phase-initialization) of your module. To quickly summarise what you should do:

- You should define a module state struct containing this type of information,
- Your module spec should contain the size of the module state struct,
- You need to initialize this struct within the `Py_mod_exec` slot.
- You need to create an `m_free` function (and ideally the other GC functions) to correctly decref your state during de-initialization.
- Within a global module function, `self` will be your module object, and so you can get the state with `PyModule_GetState(self)`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. It required me change another type I made to a heap allocated type in order to use the PyType_GetModuleState() inside my type's class functions as well as my global module functions, but it all worked out. Thanks!